# Can't install ZMQ php extension. Unable to find libzmq installation. But it installed via "brew install zmq". MacOS Mojave

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, zeromq, macos-mojave

I installed `zeromq` via `brew install zeromq`, and after tried to install php extension via `pecl install zmq-beta`. But I received error

> Unable to find libzmq installation.

I can't find the solution. I added `zmq` lib files to `$PATH` and I can "ping" it in bash. I'm using custom php instalation via brew (php@5.6).  pkg-config also installed.

Comment: Brew can't find package for dev - "Error: No formulae found in taps.". I tried libzmq3-dev, libzmq-dev, zmq-dev.

Comment: Check php.ini file. It has to include this extension and make sure that php uses that php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem! Just installed zeromq manually from master as described [here](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software) in the "Development master" section. I used first way.